# Correct the last page number of frontmatter

Tags: page-numbering, page, lastpage

I want to show the last page number of front matter. This is the code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
        Last front matter page:   &\protect\pageref{lastoffront}
    \end{tabular}
    
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \label{lastoffront}
    \clearpage
    \mainmatter
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

But, the result appear "iii". In my document, the last page number of front matter is "iv". How to correct it?

This is the screenshot of result:
[image]

This is the last page of front matter in my document:
[image]

Comment: Try moving `\label{lastoffront}` after `\clearpage`.

Comment: Thanks! that's work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reliably do it with `\label` and `\pageref`, but you can examine the page number at `\mainmatter`, after having issued a `\clearpage` that flushes the still pending contents. At that point you can look whether the page number is even or odd. If it's odd, the standard `\cleardoublepage` will not produce a blank page; we just compute the last page number by subtracting one. If the page number is even, that's the last page number in the frontmatter and the ensuing `\cleardoublepage` will generate a blank page.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\mainmatter{%
  %\cleardoublepage
  % do a different \cleardoublepage
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\relax
    % last page of the frontmatter is even
    \immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \string\gdef\string\lastpageoffront{\romannumeral\numexpr\value{page}-1\relax}%
    }%
  \else
   \immediate\write\@auxout{%
     \string\gdef\string\lastpageoffront{\romannumeral\value{page}}%
   }%
  \fi
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmattertrue
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
\providecommand{\lastpageoffront}{??}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

Last front matter page: \lastpageoffront

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

With six `\blinddocument` commands, also the second page in the TOC has text. With just one you get “iv” nonetheless.

[image]

I guess that the purpose is to restart numbering pages in Roman numerals in the back matter, is it so?